# JSF put context back after modify it

Tags: java, jsf

I am using this to access context of backing bean from another backing bean.

I am modifying property of this bean in current one. Can I put this context back?

```
TemplatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean templatePrescBean = (TemplatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean)context.getApplication()
            .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{templatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean}", TemplatePrescriptionMaintenanceBackingBean.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not necessary. You're obtaining a reference to an existing bean instance, not a copy or something. If you manipulate the reference, then it'll be "reflected" anywhere else which is also holding a reference to this instance. Java is an OO language, not a procedural language or something.

By the way, `@ManagedProperty` is a better approach to obtain a reference to another managed bean.

#### See also:

- [JSF2.0 Passing Value objects between managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934027/jsf2-0-passing-value-objects-between-managed-beans/4934770#4934770)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, I just modify property go back and see on previous page, it's changing the existing content and no need to put context back...

Comment: You're welcome. Note that this is not a JSF feature, but a general Java programming language feature. Imagine that you've a `List<SomeBean>` and need to manipulate the 1st item, so you do `SomeBean someBean = list.get(0); someBean.setSomeProperty("foo");`, do you also put it back afterwards? No, that's totally unnecessary. Java is an OO language. You work with object references, not with copied values or something like in PHP. Invest a bit more time in learning general Java.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, but yeah I am in learning phase. I thought it is similar like request or session scope, in which we are accessing that data, Do what so ever we need with that data (including modify that list or bean passed) and put/set it back on similar scope... But this is different one passing a reference....